# Why my does blur view become transparent when I combine with UIImagview?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation

I have this blur effect that combines with a UIImageView. The problem Im having is when I take a picture the blur effect becomes transparent and doesn't look the same before it was rendered. Why does this happen?

```
@IBAction func pictureButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])
    stillImageOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)


}

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

    guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation()
        else { return }

    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

    capturedImage.image = image

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.capturedImage.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    self.capturedImage.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    self.previewView.blurEffectView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.capturedImage.image = newImage
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work finally:

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

    guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation()
        else { return }

    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    capturedImage.image = image


    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view.bounds.size)
    let image2 = renderer.image { ctx in
        view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
    self.capturedImage.image = image2
}
```